# Magento 2.2.2 How to add Buy Now button with add to cart button

Tags: magento2, buy-now

I want to add both buttons `Buy Now` as well as `Add to Cart`, If user click on Buy-now it will redirect to `Checkout` page directly, for Add to Cart need default functionality. I'm using **Magento 2.2.2** using third party theme

Please suggest how to add the buy now button functionality without extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the BuyNow button on product module I would recommend for Magento 2 -:

https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow

Comment: I have tried this. but its not working with the third party theme. Am using a paid theme